# java script forms with specific fields depending on user choice

Tags: javascript, forms

I have just about come to the end of my course on javascript and I have learnt alot but im really stuck on this one.

I have to build a form for a cinema where the user selects a film and there are then options for regular seat or vip seat, different cinema locations etc and the prices depend on location and what kind of seat they select and for what movie.

I have no code to show as I truthfully dont know where to start, I have done the html part without a problem but I have no idea how to show the fields and options depending on what movie the user clicks on if that makes sense.

for example, movie 1 movie 2 movie 3, the prices for movies 1 are $16 regular seat and $20 for vip for a cinema in newyork and its $18 and $22 for one in LA. the user could pick movie 1 and it would show the locations of where its shown with dates for that cinema with the prices.

I really hope that makes sense as I'm not sure how to explain it better.

thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not really a place to go if you want someone to do your homework for you. If I understood you correctly you don't understand the task, and in which case I would recommend asking other people that have done the task for advice, or perhaps spend some more time studying wha tthe task really is.

Comment: no one really knows what they are doing, im not asking anyone to do it for me. thats the last thing i want as i wont learn anything. what should i look for in google? is it called a auto complete form or something else?

Comment: its exactly the same as ticketmaster where people pick an artist and all the relivent information appears with a final total of price.

Comment: Please at least tell me what i'm looking for when doing research so i can make a start. What is the form called which will give certain drop down options depending on user choice.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you will need a form with autocompletion, dropdowns, and a back-end for dealing with retrieval of information. You will also have to know how to get the value of dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is having a `select` and change the `inputs` that you are showing depending on the select value. This can be done appling a CSS class with `display:none` or directly using `$(#myInput).hide()` (if you are allowed to use JQuery).

There is not a `input` element that handles all that things, you need to write some logic behind, in your JS.